# Getting reproducible docker layers on different hosts

Tags: docker, dockerfile

Problem: I can't reproduce docker layers using exactly same content (on one machine or in CI cluster where something is built from git repo)

Consider this simple example

```
$ echo "test file" > test.txt
$ cat > Dockerfile <<EOF
FROM alpine:3.8

COPY test.txt /test.txt
EOF
```

If I build image on one machine with caching enabled, then last layer with copied file would be shared across images

```
$ docker build -t test:1 .
Sending build context to Docker daemon  3.072kB
Step 1/2 : FROM alpine:3.8
3.8: Pulling from library/alpine
cd784148e348: Already exists
Digest: sha256:46e71df1e5191ab8b8034c5189e325258ec44ea739bba1e5645cff83c9048ff1
Status: Downloaded newer image for alpine:3.8
 ---> 3f53bb00af94
Step 2/2 : COPY test.txt /test.txt
 ---> decab6a3fbe3
Successfully built decab6a3fbe3
Successfully tagged test:1

$ docker build -t test:2 .
Sending build context to Docker daemon  3.072kB
Step 1/2 : FROM alpine:3.8
 ---> 3f53bb00af94
Step 2/2 : COPY test.txt /test.txt
 ---> Using cache
 ---> decab6a3fbe3
Successfully built decab6a3fbe3
Successfully tagged test:2
```

But with cache disabled (or simply using another machine) I got different hash values.

```
$ docker build -t test:3 --no-cache .
Sending build context to Docker daemon  3.072kB
Step 1/2 : FROM alpine:3.8
 ---> 3f53bb00af94
Step 2/2 : COPY test.txt /test.txt
 ---> ced4dff22d62
Successfully built ced4dff22d62
Successfully tagged test:3
```

At the same time history command shows that file content was same

```
$ docker history test:1
IMAGE               CREATED             CREATED BY                                      SIZE                COMMENT
decab6a3fbe3        6 minutes ago       /bin/sh -c #(nop) COPY file:d9210c40895e

$ docker history test:3
IMAGE               CREATED             CREATED BY                                      SIZE                COMMENT
ced4dff22d62        27 seconds ago      /bin/sh -c #(nop) COPY file:d9210c40895e
```

Am I missing something or this behavior is by design?

Are there any technics to get reproducible/reusable layers that does not force me to do one of the following

1. Share docker cache across machines
2. Do a pull of "previous" image before building next

Ultimately this problem prevents me from getting thin layers with constantly changing app code while keeping layers of my dependencies in separate and infrequently changed layer.

Comment: If you run `docker test:1 -f '{{.RootFS.Layers}}` and `docker inspect test:3 -f '{{.RootFS.Layers}}`, do you see differences?

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth no, same output

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some extra googling, I found [a great post](https://andrewlock.net/caching-docker-layers-on-serverless-build-hosts-with-multi-stage-builds---target,-and---cache-from/) describing solution to this problem.

Starting from 1.13, docker has `--cache-from` option that can be used to tell docker to look at another images for layers. Important thing - image should be explicitly pulled for it to work + you still need point what image to take. It could be `latest` or any other "rolling" image you have.

Given that, unfortunately there is no way to produce same layer in "isolation", but `cache-from` solves root problem - how to eventually reuse some layers during ci build.

Comment: what if you pull the image from registry before building the new one? It should load and cache the current state, and reuse layers that are common, shouldn't it? Instead of relying on cache.

Comment: The thing is that `--cache-from` requires pulling an image as well. I have not checked it, but suspect that on a new agent 2 unrelated images will not reuse cache and that is possilble only for building same image consequently

Comment: The problem is that the cache just checks the content of the context and can't check any external resources. So if you use it across steps involving e.g. `apt-get install -y something`, it will use the existing layer and not check for newer version of the package.